# Login too long in Ubuntu 22.04.3 / GNOME 42.9

Tags: 22.04, login, gnome-session

I find the GNOME (42.9) session login too long, around 45 seconds while the boot sequence takes about 30 seconds.

Checking `journalctl -b _UID=1000` I find this error a number of times, the process may differ:

```
tracker-miner-fs-3[2948]: Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
```

The 1st time it happens, for `tracker-miner-fs-3` as shown, it takes ~15 seconds since the previous line output.

Later, I see:

```
dbus-daemon[2930]: [session uid=1000 pid=2930] Failed to activate service 'org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor': timed out (service_start_timeout=120000ms)
```

displayed ~7 seconds after the previous line.

Other times the error occurs it may take almost nothing or 2-3 seconds, I guess it's the main reason why the login time is so long.

What can I do to improve the login time?

Comment: check journalctl: `journalctl -n 50 -u udisks2.service` (this gives last 50 lines)

Comment: Last boot of today:
-- Boot 2167dcfb3d414028b49234fecfc75105 --
déc. 02 11:31:16 8570w systemd[1]: Starting Disk Manager...
déc. 02 11:31:16 8570w udisksd[1085]: udisks daemon version 2.9.4 starting
déc. 02 11:31:16 8570w udisksd[1085]: Applying configuration from /etc/udisks2/MTFDDAK128MAM-1J1-12020329411F.conf to /dev/sda
déc. 02 11:31:16 8570w udisksd[1085]: Enabled Write-Cache on /dev/sda [MTFDDAK128MAM-1J1-12020329411F]
déc. 02 11:31:17 8570w systemd[1]: Started Disk Manager.
déc. 02 11:31:17 8570w udisksd[1085]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus